# What does "Virtua" mean?

Tags: meaning

The word "Virtua" is in the name of a lot of video games, for example:

- [Virtua Tennis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtua_Tennis)
- [Virtua Fighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtua_Fighter)
- Virtua Racing

I couldn't find a definition online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find the word *virtua* either.

Many times, the game makers and webmasters choose the word close to a meaningful word (here, probably *virtual*). This generally happens as the main phrase as **a website URL** [is not available](http://virtualtennis.com/) or the phrase/game **virtual tennis** is already registered.

It's not observed that every game **name** conveys a message or have **a proper spelling**. Game makers and webmasters do enjoy such flexibility.

Answer (score 5):

It's a name, made up on the spur of the moment, probably meant to resemble Virtual. Brand names and trade marks don't have the follow the traditional rules of grammar :)

Comment: True, although the rules of grammar have nothing to say one way or the other about *virtua*.

Answer (score 1):

It's a word that was made up by Sega and applied to many of their early 3D games.